# simple cursor pagination, getRequestForPagedResults() returns NULL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am making a very simple call to the facebook API to get some posts on a public page and the comments

```
accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
          accessToken,
          "/319895538134510",
          new GraphRequest.Callback() {
               @Override
               public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                     processResponse(response, true);
               }
          });

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "posts{created_time,message,id,comments{from,message,attachment},attachments}");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

The request runs fine and I get the desired data.
But when I try to fetch the next page of results

```
GraphRequest nextResultsRequests = gr.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
if (nextResultsRequests != null) { 
       Log.d("aspen", "was null");
}
```

but always returns a NULL graphRequest even though the pagination data is clearly there
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone struggling with the same problem,
the reason was that their was an additional hierarchy level in the JSON response ("posts") which was a result of the query I was making ?fields=posts{created_time,me....

which you can fix using /posts?fields=....
and then a non-null return occurs